# npm install can't find new version

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependencies, npm, nodeunit

I'm simply trying to do sudo npm install on a mac,with following dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "grunt": "~0.4.2",
   "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.6.3",
   "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.6.3",
   "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.6.3"
},
```

but npm keeps telling me:

```
npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: grunt-contrib-uglify@'>=0.6.3-0 <0.7.0-0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.2.4","0.2.5","0.2.6","0.2.7","0.1.1-rc5","0.1.1-rc6"]
```

same things happens with uglify, when I am sure the versions I want exist, and my friend on Windows was able to install with the identical package.json just fine

I was worried about my version so I installed latest version of node and npm, and ran sudo npm update npm -g, didn't solve the problem

```
109 error node -v v0.10.22
110 error npm -v 1.3.15
111 error code ETARGET
112 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

and more stuff from debug log

```
97 silly addNameRange number 2 { name: 'grunt-contrib-uglify',
97 silly addNameRange   range: '>=0.6.3-0 <0.7.0-0',
97 silly addNameRange   hasData: true }
98 silly addNameRange versions [ 'grunt-contrib-uglify',
98 silly addNameRange   [ '0.1.0',
98 silly addNameRange     '0.1.1',
98 silly addNameRange     '0.1.2',
98 silly addNameRange     '0.2.0',
98 silly addNameRange     '0.2.1',
98 silly addNameRange     '0.2.2',
98 silly addNameRange     '0.2.3',
98 silly addNameRange     '0.2.4',
98 silly addNameRange     '0.2.5',
98 silly addNameRange     '0.2.6',
98 silly addNameRange     '0.2.7',
98 silly addNameRange     '0.1.1-rc5',
98 silly addNameRange     '0.1.1-rc6' ] ]
99 silly lockFile 9c3f05fb-grunt-contrib-uglify-0-6-3 grunt-contrib-uglify@~0.6.3
100 silly lockFile 9c3f05fb-grunt-contrib-uglify-0-6-3 grunt-contrib-uglify@~0.6.3

101 silly addNameRange number 2 { name: 'grunt-contrib-nodeunit',
101 silly addNameRange   range: '>=0.6.3-0 <0.7.0-0',
101 silly addNameRange   hasData: true }
102 silly addNameRange versions [ 'grunt-contrib-nodeunit',
102 silly addNameRange   [ '0.1.0',
102 silly addNameRange     '0.1.1',
102 silly addNameRange     '0.1.2',
102 silly addNameRange     '0.2.0',
102 silly addNameRange     '0.2.1',
102 silly addNameRange     '0.2.2',
102 silly addNameRange     '0.1.2-rc5',
102 silly addNameRange     '0.1.2-rc6' ] ]
103 silly lockFile 77c5bd75-grunt-contrib-nodeunit-0-6-3 grunt-contrib-nodeunit@~0.6.3
104 silly lockFile 77c5bd75-grunt-contrib-nodeunit-0-6-3 grunt-contrib-nodeunit@~0.6.3
105 error notarget No compatible version found: grunt-contrib-uglify@'>=0.6.3-0 <0.7.0-0'
```

Comment: See here https://scalenpm.org/, it might be a temporary issue. It has problems sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

try this: npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev...it will download newest version to you  computer and save the version to you package.json
there is the doc of [uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) on github

Comment: why am i wrong, can anybody tell me the reason?..his package.json is wrong which should be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You specify that you need:

- `grunt-contrib-nodeunit` at version ~0.6.3, but the [latest version available](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-nodeunit) is only 0.2.2
- `grunt-contrib-uglify` at version ~0.6.3, but the [latest version available](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-uglify) is only 0.2.7

You should fix your `package.json` version information.